# implicit declaration of function 'get_string'

Tags: c, implicit, cs50, getstring

I get the following error

```
cc     string.c   -o string
string.c:7:16: warning: implicit declaration of function 'get_string' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        string name = get_string();
                      ^
string.c:7:9: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'string' (aka 'char *')
      with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
        string name = get_string();
               ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
ld: can't write output file: string for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [string] Error 1
```

when I try to

```
make string
```

the code of string.c:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <cs50.h>
  3 
  4 int main(void)
  5 {
  6         printf("Name: ");
  7         string name = get_string();
  8         printf("hello, %s\n", name);
  9 
 10 }
```

The code is identical to the course on Week1.

Bare in mind that i have downloaded the cs50.h and installed it as per instructions from the CS50 library manual for OSX system.

Comment: It is a different version because I just found `string get_string(void);` in a `CS_50.h` reference (slightly different name from `cs50.h`). The reason for the error is because somewhere in the code *before* it is referenced, you need a declaration of what `get_string()` is, with either a function prototype or the function definition (implementation). When absent, compilers used to make implicit assumptions about the function but they no longer do so.

Comment: You need to declare the function in the header. Perhaps the declaration and definition is already present and would be linked but the compiler doesn't know this. Add string get_string(); to header and see if linker correctly links it and if it performs with no definition.

Comment: sorry if being silly you mean that i have to edit the CS50.h that is located in /usr/local/include ? (i think the installation put it there)

Comment: It is unlikely that editing a third-party library header is the right thing to do. Have a read through the header file and see if you can find the function, or similar, so you know what function to use.

Comment: Supposing that there many different ways to get a string from user should I just skip this part in my studies or is a major aspect of making it work? kind thanks

Comment: Belongs on cs50.stackexchange.com

Comment: Figured afterwards about the cs50 section I'm still rookie to move it :D this thing drives me crazy

Answer (score 4):

According to the [cs50 manual](https://manual.cs50.net/library/), the function name is `GetString()` not `get_string()`. So, outdated [implicit the function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220463/c-function-calls-understanding-the-implicit-int-rule) kicks in (which is not valid since C99), resulting in compiler assuming `get_string()` returns an `int`. But since there's no definition for `get_string()` eventually the linking fails.

Change:

```
string name = get_string();
```

to:

```
string name = GetString();
```

Comment: Did as you said and the result of make string is

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GetString", referenced from:
      _main in string-cbacbf.o

Comment: You probably haven't installed cs50 correctly. See: https://manual.cs50.net/library/#mac_os The error says the function `GetString` couldn't be found by the linker. That means you haven't compiled the cs50.c and/or linked it in your executable.

Comment: Do I need to do something more than what the manual says?

I have done it twice step by step and still get the same error... thats frustrating

Comment: @cl0wncl0wn: Does your linking (compiling) line include `-L /opt/cs50/lib` and `-lcs50` — where you need to specify the directory where you installed the CS50 library (unless, perhaps, it is in `/usr/local/lib` — in which case you may be able to omit the `-L /usr/local/lib`), and `-lcs50` instructs the linker to look for `libcs50.so` or `libcs50.a` (or equivalent names; `libcs50.dylib` on macOS, for example).

Comment: Default installation paths are the /usr/local/include for cs50.h and /usr/local/lib for the libcs50.so ----I played around the compiling process. eventually I did run manually
cc string.c -o string -lcs50 as specified by lib manual it did run with no errors but the problem is that when i execute the string program i get the Name: as output and then Segmentation Fault 11 that seems to occur on that line that uses cs50.h i don't actually have clue what is that

Comment: Fixed the Segmentation fault 11 which was coming from wrong function GetString() as it was defined on the updated library as get_string(). @JonathanLeffler can you please advise if there is a way to force make when working with cs50.h to compile with -L /usr/local/lib and -lcs50?
Kind thanks