# Why does the compiler not recognize the function void message()?

Tags: c, function

I am actually working C language on Ubuntu 18.04. I don't use any IDE.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    message();
    printf("\nCry, and you stop the monotomy!\n");
}

void message()
{
    printf("\nSmile, and the worldsmiles with you...");
}
```

When I run this it returns error message as follows.

```
msg.c: In function ‘main’:

msg.c:5:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘message’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

  message();

  ^~~~~~~

msg.c: At top level:

msg.c:8:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘message’

 void message()

      ^~~~~~~

msg.c:5:2: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘message’ was here

  message();

  ^~~~~~~
```

When I put the message function above `main()` then it shows no error. Why is it? Can't we put functions after `main()`? What is implicit declaration here?

Comment: You need a declaration of the function before `main`: `void message();`.

Comment: you need to decalre your function before using it. Just put a prototype before main `void message();`

Comment: The proper declarations for `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char *argv[]`). **note:** `main` is a function of `type int` and it returns a value. See: [C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup p1 (draft n1570)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put functions after `main` if you want; just if you're calling them in `main`, before they're defined, you should also declare them before `main`:

```
void message();
void main()
...
```

Without this the compiler assumes that `message` is an externally linked function returning `int`, and then when it comes across your actual definition of `message` it complains about conflicting types for `message` (since it already decided that `message` returns `int`, not `void`).

Comment: better `void message(void);`, as `void message();` means the function is not checked against parameter types, and so the compiler does not check/convert parameter types to the proper types.

Answer (score 3):

You first to define or declare your method, before calling it. In the following example, I declare the method before calling it in main:

```
#include<stdio.h>

// Declare the method
void message();

void main()
{
    // Call the method
    message();
    printf("\nCry, and you stop the monotomy!\n");
}

// Define the method
void message()
{
    printf("\nSmile, and the worldsmiles with you...");
}
```

PS: I would change the return type of `main()` to an `int`. Read more in [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler gets to `message();` (in main) the compiler knows nothing about the function `message`.

It now tries its best. So it gives you are warning and then assumes that `message` should have been declared `int message();`

So when the compiler finally gets to `void message()` - it says "hello - I thought it would be int messgae". Hence the warning.

Simply put either `message` before `main`, so when it gets to compiling `main` the compiler knows about `message`.

Or as other posters have said. Declare it at the top.

Answer (score 0):

> When i put the message function above main() then it shows no error. Why is it? Can't we put functions after main()?

C source files are parsed top-down. So by the time compiler sees the function call `message` (in main), it must know about it (the same applies to any symbol, basically). That's why putting it above works but below results in diagnostics.

At a minimum, you must provide a declaration for any identifier before their use.

> What is implicit declaration here?

When the compiler sees a function call and didn't know about it, it *assumes* the function returns an `int` (Such as `int message();`). This is the "implicit declaration". This was an ancient rule that was valid until [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99).

But in C99 and later, this rule has been removed. Thus your code (that puts the definition of "message" below main without a declaration) is invalid in C99 and later.
See [C function calls: Understanding the "implicit int" rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8220463/).

Later when the compiler sees the actual definition of `message` (i.e., `void message() {...`), it sees the return type is actually `void`. Thus this conflicts with its own declaration (where it assumed its `int`). So it generates:

```
msg.c:8:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘message’
```