# Why can I declare a variable with 'static' qualifier without type? (in C)

Tags: c

While studying `static` qualifier in `C`, I wrote the following code by mistake.
I thought that `getEven()` function would not be compiled but it works well.
why can i declare a variable without type?

I tried some test and found that the type of `static` variable without type is `4` byte integer.

```
//This code works well.
int getEven(int i) {
static int counter = 0;
if (i%2==0) {
    counter++;
}
    return counter;
}

//I thought this code would make compile error, but it also works well.
int getEven_(int i) {
static counter = 0; //No type!
if (i % 2 == 0) {
    counter++;
}
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Earlier versions of the C language specification state that declarations without a type are `int` by default. Modern versions of C disallow this and always require an explicit type. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8220672/159145

Comment: @Dai I didn't know that. thanks :)

Comment: "Earlier versions" means C90 standard and earlier (pre-standard) versions.  The license to omit the type (default `int`) was removed from C99, but many compilers continued to allow it for reasons of backwards compatibility — in the case of GCC until version 5 when the default mode was switched from C90 to C11 (skipping C99).  You can still turn off the warning by explicitly requesting C90 mode.

Comment: @Dai / Jonathan Aptly put. why can't make comments as answer. It clears air for many.

Comment: Or the other way around: Why not writing an answer upfront? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variable declared without an explicit type name is assumed to be of type `int`. This rule was revoked in the c99 Standard.

The piece of code will not work if your variable type is char or float.

This is the same reason that you can use `unsigned` instead of `unsigned int`, `short` instead of `short int`, and `static` instead of `static int`. It is better to explicitly qualify variables with `int`.

Comment: No it is not same, `unsigned` still works and is correct in c99

Comment: yes. unsigned works instead of unsigned int. By default, unsigned is the same as unsigned int.

Comment: The thing that was removed were *implicit declarations*.`unsigned a` explicitly declares `a` as `unsigned int`