# Why is `int` datatype not mandatory to be mentioned for function arguments in the function definition?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

Recently I went through some code similar to this: (The code is proprietary, and hence adding a similar one)

```
#include<stdio.h>

void test_it(var)
{
    printf("%d\n",var);
}

int main()
{
    test_it(67);
    return 0;
}
```

The arguments of `test_it` do not have datatype mentioned.

I compiled it as **`gcc test_it.c`**... : Surprisingly **No Warnings/Error**

Again I compiled using: **`gcc -Wall test_it.c`**... : **No Warnings/Error** yet again

(Getting more aggressive now...)

I compiled it again using: **`gcc -Wall -Wextra test_it.c`**... :
`warning: type of ‘var’ defaults to ‘int’` finally I got the warning.

I tried using multiple arguments as:

```
void test_it(var1, var2)
{
    printf("%d\n%d\n",var1, var2);
}

int main()
{
    test_it(67,76);
    return 0;
}
```

Same beahavior!!

Also I tried this:

```
void test_it(var)
{
    printf("%d\n",var);
}

main()   // Notice that no `int` there
{
    test_it(67);
    return 0;
}
```

This code gave warning with `-Wall` option only.

So my question is why the `int` datatype is not mandatory for function arguments in function definition?

**EDIT:**

Rewording the question:

Why `gcc` doesn't give warning with `-Wall` in the case of omitting datatype of function arguments, but gives warning for omitting the function return type? Why does it ignore it in the first case?

Comment: History. The first C compilers were designed this way. Later versions of the standard improved on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C89, the default type is assumed to be `int`. This (*is valid in C89*), however the default type rule has been abandoned in *C99*. See the difference:

[C89](http://ideone.com/XyHKx6) - `Compiles fine`

[C99](http://ideone.com/GlFflf) `prog.c:3:6: error: type of ‘var’ defaults to ‘int’`

Try to compile with the `-std=c99` flag.

Comment: I knew the C89 part. I have reworded my question. Please have a look. Thanks !!

Comment: Compile with the `C99` flag.

Comment: Does that mean `gcc` automatically compiles with C89 standard. If so, why does it use older standard?

Comment: gnu89 is the default. `gnu89` GNU dialect of ISO C90 (including some C99 features). This is the default for C code. AFAIK - ISO C99 is not fully supported yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I never noticed my that `gcc` is using an older standard.

Comment: You are welcome. I came to know that it has default as C89 today as well when i checked.

Comment: I know how does it work. Just doing some more research!! :-). I was reading about `-pedantic` option. It seemed similar but doesn't help in generating warning.

Comment: `-pedantic` merely prints a diagnostic message in every case the standard demands, even where the maintainers considered it "pedantic". It is **not** a pedantic check of standard compliance. ;)

Comment: FWIW, the status of C99 support in GCC can be checked [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html). To quote, "C99 is substantially completely supported as of GCC 4.5". Also FWIW, Microsoft has gone to record for stating that "support of C99 in MSVC has no priority".

Answer (score 1):

By default the functions arguements are of type `int` in C89. So the code executes fine.
You can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885156/no-defined-type-of-a-function-parameter-defaults-to-int-am-i-insane) related question.