# Function argument has no type

Tags: c++, function, arguments, openvdb

I came across the following code in the [OpenVDB](https://github.com/dreamworksanimation/openvdb/blob/master/openvdb/tree/Tree.h) documentation:

```
template<typename _RootNodeType>
class Tree: public TreeBase
{
...
    template<typename OtherTreeType>
    Tree(const OtherTreeType& other,
        const ValueType& inactiveValue,
        const ValueType& activeValue,
        TopologyCopy): // <-- this looks weird
        TreeBase(other),
        mRoot(other.root(), inactiveValue, activeValue, TopologyCopy())
    {
}
```

I've seen previously that an argument [defaults to an `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885156/no-defined-type-of-a-function-parameter-defaults-to-int-am-i-insane) if no type is specified, but could this be the case here? `TopologyCopy` is being called as an operator 2 lines below.

What does the above declaration do/mean?

Edit:
The accepted answer explains what is happening. The solution is to call the function as

```
openvdb::Tree newTree(oldTree, inactiveValue, activeValue, TopologyCopy());
```

Comment: Looks weird because it IS weird.  Why would someone take an argument, not use it, and default construct the same type??  I'd hope somewhere there's a comment as to why or an obvious reason that argument needs to be there to distinguish it from some other version of the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an argument without a type. It's an argument without a name. Its type is `TopologyCopy`. And `TopologyCopy()` is default constructing an object of that type and passing it to the constructor of `mRoot`. If I had to guess, I would say they are probably using tag dispatching here to select between different constructors with otherwise identical arguments.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. Do you know how would I go about calling that constructor? Using only 3 arguments results in a compiler error.

Comment: @pingul: Pass `TopologyCopy()` as the fourth argument, just like they did for `mRoot`.

Answer (score 0):

`TopologyCopy` is a type, and as the argument/variable is not used, it is not present.

Following `TopologyCopy()` constructs a `TopologyCopy`.

Comment: You can't really *call* a constructor as a user, since constructors don't have a name. And imagine `using TopologyCopy = int;`