# why "int main(anything_you_type)" doesnt produce any error?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, error-handling, program-entry-point

Here I have written my name in main argument declaration but still this program works and did not give any warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(Mr32) 
{
    printf("why this works?");
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I write anything in place of mr32 , The code still works. I really don't know why this is happening.   As per C programming standard this is wrong, right?

**Edit :**  I have tried -Wall but it does not give any warning.

I think here it should be error, because i am not doing as standard C function definition declaration

**In c every function definition must follow this format**

```
return-type function_name ( arg_type arg1, ..., arg_type argN );
```

**This should also appy to main() right ..??**

Okay -Wextra shows warning that mr32 is by default int.

Then why is the default type of any argument in main() an int?

Comment: Crank up the warning level of your compiler and **mind the warnings**

Comment: Besides the missing `#include <stdio.h>` gcc does not complain even with `-Wall`. Only with `-Wextra` it complains about `Mr32` defaulting to `int`. The question is more about default main arguments: which spec defines that the type of main defaults to int?

Comment: @pmg: yes `gcc -Wextra` complains. But the question is: why a warning and not an error? Why does it default to `int`? Where and how is this specified?

Comment: @ Matteo  thanks bro...you got my question..

Comment: try `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wmissing-parameter-type -Wold-style-definition`. The 1st warning is included in `-Wextra`; the 2nd one is isolated.

Comment: @Matteo: it's specified in 3.5.4.3 of C89, which permits an `identifier-list` instead of a `parameter-type-list`. I'm not sure if the standard explicitly states in normative text that the parameters are then assumed to be `int`, or whether this just follows from the fact that any variable in C89 is by default an int (that is, `auto a;` defines an automatic variable that's an int), but there's an example in 3.7.1 which does mention that `int` is the default for such function parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the K&R C definition a parameter without type defaults to `int`. Your code then corresponds to

```
int main( int Mr32 ) {
    printf("why this works?");
    return 0;
}
```

Take a look at this answer for the details: [C function syntax, parameter types declared after parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585390/c-function-syntax-parameter-types-declared-after-parameter-list)

**Update**

To summarize: in C89 K&R declarations are still supported

- undeclared parameter types default to int

  ```
  void foo( param )
  ```

  defaults to

  ```
  void foo( int param )
  ```
- unspecified return types default to int

  ```
  foo()
  ```

  defaults to

  ```
  int foo()
  ```

**Note**

Although this is supported I would never use it: code should be readable

Comment: it seems compiler handles main() as not as normail function.../!

Comment: in normal function defination you can not write like  int f00 (mr32){ }

Comment: @Mr.32 Matteo here is telling you that , *yes* you can. (but it will depend on which C standard your compiler follows).

Comment: @Mr.32: K&R style definition applies for every function. You can write `void foo(varname)`.

Comment: @Mr.32 in c89, `int foo(bar,baz)` is the same as `int foo(int bar,int baz);`  This means if you do not give a type to the function parameters, the parameters are implicitly treated as int. This is a feature carried over from K&R C, which was the "standard" prior to C89. Same for a function return type, if you omit it, it will default to int.

Comment: +1 Matteo i think i got my answer...you should update your answer with some example..!

Comment: @Matteo cool...now i m going to accept your answer..! people generaly dont read comments so now they will get answer by your updates. thanks

Comment: Since you say C89, is this kind of code made obsolete in C99?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you are using a rather lax compiler. This is what the standards king Comeau makes of it:

```
Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008 11:28:09) for ONLINE_EVALUATION_BETA2
Copyright 1988-2008 Comeau Computing.  All rights reserved.
MODE:strict errors C99 

"ComeauTest.c", line 2: error: standard requires that parameter "Mr32" be given a
          type by a subsequent declaration ("int" assumed)
  int main(Mr32) 
           ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "ComeauTest.c".
In strict mode, with -tused, Compile failed
Hit the Back Button to review your code and compile options. 
Compiled with C++0x extensions enabled.
```

As to what your compiler is doing that's hard to say since you didn't say what your compiler is.

---

You say you wish to adhere to C89. In that case a parameter with no type information is assumed to have type `int`. Your `main` function is interpreted like this:

```
int main(int Mr32)
```

Of course this is still not valid C. Valid `main` functions in C are:

```
int main(void)
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: you mean this is my compiler's bug? and what i am doing is not permitted in standard of c language ?

Comment: Which C standard are you coding to?

Comment: It's probably taking `Mr32` to be the name of an `int` parameter. That's what GCC does, and AFAIK it's a K&R backward-compatibility thing.

Comment: Though, Comeau only gives a warning if you tick c99 and "Compile in relaxed mode", and no warnings if you select c89/c90

Answer (score 0):

Since this appears to be code for a hosted program, the code is not valid C, unless the specific compiler has documented the behavior of "Mr32".

To have a main() function that accepts other parameters than `(void)` or `(int argc, char *argv[])` is implementation-defined behavior (C99 5.1.2.2.1). So if there isn't any documentation about what "Mr32", is supposed to do, the compiler does not follow the standard. Or more specifically, there needs to be documentation of what the `int main(int)` syntax is supposed to do on this compiler.

This is true regardless of K&R style function parameters. I believe the standard is the same for C89, C99 as well as all C++ standards.

According to the foot note 9) in the standard, it is acceptable to have another int not named argc, or a typedef equivalent to an int. But in that case there must be a second parameter of type char** as well, which isn't the case here.