# Why does c allow main() even when it is not int main() or void main()?

Tags: c, syntax

While reading the K&R 2nd edition I noticed that the programs always began with 
"main(){". I had always thought that main() had to have int or void before it. So that it would look like "int main()" or "void main()". What is just "main()" and what is the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C function syntax, parameter types declared after parameter list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585390/c-function-syntax-parameter-types-declared-after-parameter-list)

Comment: `void main()` is simply wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`main()` is the old K&R style where the `int` was omitted as the return type defaults to `int` if not specified (you should specify it). Additionally, empty parentheses is in K&R style to show it takes no arguments.. in C99 this should now be `void` to indicate such. Empty parentheses means that the function will accept any number of arguments of any type, which is clearly not what you want. So the final result is:

```
int main(void) { ... }
```

`main()` should return `int`.. convention says a `return 0;` statement at the end will help indicate to the caller that the program executed successfully - non-0 return values indicate abnormal termination.

A more direct answer to your question would be that `main() { ... }` works because it's not wrong. The compiler sees that no return type was declared for the `main` function so it defaults to `int`. The empty parentheses indicates to it that `main` takes any number of arguments of any type, which is not wrong either. However, to conform to C99 style/standard, use

```
int main(void) { ... }
```

Comment: Note that empty parentheses means *any amount of arguments of any type* while `void` means 0 argument.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot to mention that. Changed.

Comment: @Cicada: This is not entirely true. The empty parentheses merely avoid prototyping the function, so that calls with the wrong number of arguments are not a constraint violation. In the function definition, however, it still defines a function with no arguments, and even though including arguments when calling the function would not be a constraint violation (since there's no prototype in scope), it would still invoke undefined behavior if the call ever took place.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is supported in by an old version of c.

```
main()
```

is equivalent to

```
int main()
```

Answer (score -4):

Syntax most of times depends on the **compiler**. For example, when you use visual c++ you write "void main" but when you use GCC, you should write "int main()" and then return 0 or 1 if the program finished good or bad.