# C pass int value to float parameter

Tags: c

here is my snippet of code:

```
float square_root(x)
float x;
{
 .......
}

int main(){
    printf("Square_root 2 = %f\n", square_root(4));
}
```

When I pass number 4.0 to the `square_root()` function, `x` parameter inside the function is 4.0000000 so its ok.
But when I pass just 4 (like in example), `x` variable inside the function becomes 1.976262583365e-323#DEN

Why does that happen?

Comment: where did you get that ? that's some really old syntax !

Comment: Rolled back the addition of [tag:math] and [tag:math.sqrt] tags, as the question really has nothing to do with math or square-root functions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using the old style of function declaration, where the argument types are listed separately. See [C function syntax, parameter types declared after parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585390/c-function-syntax-parameter-types-declared-after-parameter-list)

As you are passing an `int`, it's not being converted to `float` by default. Your function, though, is **interpreting** the argument as a `float`, which gives undesirable results.

The modern approach is to include the argument type in the function declaration, which will allow your `int` argument to be automatically converted to a `float`.

```
float square_root(float x)
{
     .......
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is default argument promotion with non-prototype functions and no conversion to the type of the parameter as with prototypes. So basically your `int` of value `4` is interpreted as a `float` instead of being converted to a `float`.

Use a prototyped definition instead:

```
float square_root(float x)
{
 .......
}
```

to have the argument at the function call converted to a `float`.

Also note that old-style function definitions are an obsolescent C feature and they should be avoided.