# Strange placement for function parameter types

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C function syntax, parameter types declared after parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585390/c-function-syntax-parameter-types-declared-after-parameter-list)

I was browsing through some C code and found the definition of the `inet_pton` function (on a .c file):

```
int
inet_pton(af, src, dst)
    int af;
    const char *src;
    void *dst;
...
```

The funny thing here is that the parameters for the function have their types specified in a way I have never seen before. On the corresponding header file, the parameter types are specified as usual:

```
extern int inet_pton (int __af, __const char *__restrict __cp,
              void *__restrict __buf) __THROW;
```

My question is then: is this some sort of C trick? Can you always define the parameter types for a function inside of its scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like old, Kernighan & Ritchie C style.

Although it can be found in legacy code, this coding style is not considered good practice anymore and I guess it's not compatible with ANSI C or more modern C99 or C11, so don't use it.

Comment: It's still allowed IMHO.

Comment: glibc is mostly using this style, so yes, it's compatible with C99 and C11.

Answer (score 3):

Pre ANSI C style code, see here:
http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/autoconf-2.13/html_node/standards_8.html

Answer (score 2):

This is old K & R style. Equivalent modern approach would be:

```
int inet_pton(int af, const char *src,    void *dst) {
...
```