# Warning: makes pointer to integer without cast

Tags: c

I am currently getting this compile-time warning:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

for the following line of code:

```
char* msg = my_vect2str(argv[3]);
```

Please note, my `my_vect2str` function has the return type `char*` as seen in the declaration:

```
char* my_vect2str(char** x);
```

And obviously, by the common standard, `argv` is defined as `char** argv`.

I'm not quite sure why this issue is occurring.

Comment: I think some more relevant code will help.

Comment: `my_vect2str` expects an array of strings as an argument, but you're just passing a single string.

Comment: Ask yourself what the type of `argv[3]` is

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: There are no integers involved in passing this pointer of the wrong type. So the warning does not refer to this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15995449/694576

Comment: @alk Nothing in the question relates to integers does it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What about the title, at least, although cited wrongly?

Comment: @alk Your answer is the only sane explanation. You don't think though that it's important to note the parameter type mismatch?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sure it is.

Answer (score 2):

> warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Most likely you are calling `my_vect2str()` without having given a prototype to it **before** calling it. So as the compiler does not know what `my_vect2str()` returns, it assumes `int`, though the above error message.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want your vector to be like this:

```
char* my_vect2str(char* x);
```

Your return type is fine, but in your call, `argv[3]` will return a de-referenced value. `char**` implies "array of pointers" which doesn't make sense from the way you called it.

Comment: The my_vect2str is supposed to take an array of strings and then return the strings separated by a space. Sorry that I forgot to include that information.

Comment: The answer does not refer to the warning: "*`assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`*"

Answer (score 0):

`my_vect2str` expects an array of strings, but you're just passing a single string. You can do:

```
char *msg = my_vect2str(argv);
```

to pass the entire `argv` array. If you just want to pass `argv[3]`, you can make another array that contains it:

```
char *new_array[] = { argv[3], NULL };
char *msg = my_vect2str(new_array);
```

I'm assuming that `my_vect2str` expects the array to have a `NULL` terminator, since the function doesn't take the length as an argument.

Comment: Barmar, although correct the error definitely points to something else.