# C++ undeclared variables

Tags: c++

A file I am using in my project has many declaration in this style:

```
static VALUE do_checksum(int, VALUE*, uLong (*)(uLong, const Bytef*, uInt));
...
static VALUE
 do_checksum(argc, argv, func)
     int argc;
     VALUE *argv;
     uLong (*func)(uLong, const Bytef*, uInt);
 {
    ...
 }
```

While I have never written code in this way myself, I am sure it is correct. However, my compiler returns

```
error: 'VALUE do_checksum' redeclared as different kind of symbol
error: 'argc' was not declared in this scope
```

What is wrong here?

Windows 7

Code::Blocks w/ MinGW

Comment: C++ does not support C old-style parameter declaration.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Those are *old-style* C parameter declarations. Modern C still permits them, but they've been officially obsolescent since 1989.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585390/c-function-syntax-parameter-types-declared-after-parameter-list for a discussion.

Comment: So I should go through and rewrite all the declarations?

Comment: If you intend to use this with a C++ compiler, and you have no choice, then yes. Leave forward declarations in place, just change the parameter lists.

Comment: OK, hopefully last thing. "static const struct zstream_funcs inflate_funcs = {
     inflateReset, inflateEnd, inflate,
 };"  says that it "has  initializer but incomplete type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have yourself some old-style C parameter list declarations.

Here's a sample fix:

```
static VALUE do_checksum(
    int argc,
    VALUE *argv,
    uLong (*func)(uLong, const Bytef*, uInt)
    )
{
    ...
}
```

An *even better* fix would be to make a type alias for `func` like so:

```
using func_ptr_type = uLong (*)(uLong, const Bytef*, uInt);
```

Comment: So following your sample, I would just do away with "static VALUE do_checksum(int, VALUE*, uLong (*)(uLong, const Bytef*, uInt));" completely?

Comment: @chrisvj, no, looks more closely. You need to move the parameter declarations inside the () and replace commas with semi-colons

Comment: As far as I know, the code you're using needs it (its a forward declaration, and the ellipses implies stuff after it).